# An inequality for an integral over hyperplane from Young's inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations

\begin{align*}
\int_L|u|^p\,\mathrm{d}x' &< \int_{\{x_n=0\}} T|u|^p\,\mathrm{d}x=-\int_{B^+}(T|u|^p)_{x_n}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=-\int_{B^+}(|u|^pT_{x^n}+p|u|^{p-1}(sgn(u))u_{x_n}T)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&< C\int_{B^+}(|u|^p+|Du|^p)\,\mathrm{d}x,
\end{align*}
where $x'= (x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_{n-1})\in\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$.

How does it make sense?

The above is from the book Partial Differential Equation by Evens on page 274. Can someone help me understand this? I can understand how to get from the first line to the second, but I don't know how to obtain the last inequality(the third line). The book says the last inequalit is obtained through Young's inequality, but I don't see how Young's inequality is applied here.

Answer (score 0):

The second line is obtained by the product rule:
$$
(T|u|^p)_{x_n}
= |u|^pT_{x_n} + T(|u|^p)_{x_n}  
$$
followed by the chain rule (twice): 
$$
(|u|^p)_{x_n}  = p |u|^{p-1}(|u|)_{x_n} = p |u|^{p-1}\operatorname{sgn}(u) u_{x_n}
$$
The reason for $\operatorname{sgn}$ appearing is that it's the derivative of the absolute value function, $|x|' = \operatorname{sgn}x$.

Also, your assumptions on $T$ (called $\zeta$ in the book) are not correct, it should be $1$ on most of the ball (which includes the set $L$, which is not the whole boundary of $B^+$). This is why we have the first inequality in the chain. The proof would make more sense to you if you got the assumptions correctly.

Comment: First, thank you for your answer. But, my question is not resolved yet. The second line that appears in my question now is not the second line before edit made by someone else. My original second line was actually the last inequality. I understood all algebraic manipulation in there including the product rule untill the last inequality appears. The book says the last inequality is there by Young's inequality, but I don't see how Young's inequality was applied to obtain the last inequality.